# Declare a list with list of lists

Tags: java, list, generics, linked-list, declaration

```
List<List<Integer>> l = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
List<List<Integer>> l2 = new List<LinkedList<Integer>>();
List<List<Integer>> l3 = new LinkedList<List<Integer>();
List<List<Integer>> l4 = new LinkedList<>();
```

I cannot understand why only the third and the fourth statements work.

Comment: Same reason that you can't do `LinkedList<Base> list = new LinkedList<Derived>();`.

Comment: The second one doesn't work because `List` is an interface. You can't make a `new` interface without an implementation.

Comment: I'd recommend option 4, `List<List<Integer>> l4 = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first declaration does not work because a `LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>` is not a `List<List<Integer>>`. For example, by the declaration, you could add an `ArrayList<Integer>` to a `List<List<Integer>>` (a list of lists of integers). However, an `ArrayList<Integer>` could not be added to a `LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>` (a linked list of linked lists of integers).

The second initialization, starting with a `new List` could not work, as `List` is an interface, not a class, so it cannot be initialized with the `new` operator.

Comment: @cricket_007 That's an example of an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) (and not an interface).